# child div height of 100% being ignored

Tags: html, css

I'm using peter's excellent example for a 100% height div with a sticky footer ([HERE](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/examples/csslayout1.html)). I've omitted the footer parts a i'm not using it.

However, whenever i use a child div and try to do the same thing it doesn't work. I want a child div to also take 100% of its parent's height. Here is CSS:

```
<style>


    html,body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
        background:gray;

        font-family:arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:small;
        color:#666;
    }



    div#container {
        position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
        margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
        width:750px;
        background:#f0f0f0;

        height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
        height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

        min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
    }

    div#header {
        padding:1em;
        background:#ddd url("../csslayout.gif") 98% 10px no-repeat;
        border-bottom:6px double gray;
    }


    div#content {
        padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
        position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
        margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */

        height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
        height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

        min-height:100%; /* real browsers */            
    }
    div#content_subdiv{
        padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
        background:#999;
        height:100%;

        color:#fff;
    }


</style>
```

and here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="container"> 

    <div id="header"> 
        <h1>CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer</h1> 
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget massa dolor, rhoncus tempor nunc. Donec tempor odio eget purus vehicula auctor. </p> 
    </div> 

    <div id="content"> 

        <p> 
    Aenean quam mauris, iaculis non aliquet quis, facilisis sed turpis. Cras id erat velit, nec bibendum erat. Vivamus feugiat purus vitae velit dictum in vestibulum ante tristique. Vestibulum ut massa vel justo eleifend consectetur eget ut nisi. Phasellus ut diam nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent blandit gravida facilisis. Donec elementum faucibus gravida. Nullam nec enim velit, ac scelerisque justo. Pellentesque lacus metus, adipiscing nec congue a, volutpat sollicitudin eros. Donec tortor leo, tempor non viverra at, molestie sed dui. Nullam ipsum purus, tempus elementum tincidunt id, iaculis at lectus. Vestibulum viverra mi in mauris ultrices sollicitudin
        </p> 
        <div id="content_subdiv"> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /></div>
    </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: To those people who say "Everything you can do with tables can be done with CSS", then solve this question. Else i'm going to use a big fat table in my HTML for layout purposes.

Comment: @capdragon You want the child DIV to take 100% of the parent's height? But what about the paragraph that is also inside the parent? The paragraph takes up some vertical space so the child DIV cannot take all 100% of the parents height...

Comment: @Sime The subdiv should take up the remaining space

Comment: @capdragon Now that makes sense :) I'll look into it...

Comment: @capdragon You could make it work with absolute positioning. Would that be OK with you?

Comment: @capdragon 1. Just for the record, I refuted your claim that there is something that cannot be done with CSS `:)` 2. CSS 3 has some advanced layout mechanisms, so there might be a CSS 3 solution to your issue. However, my CSS 3 knowledge is still pretty weak.

Comment: @Sime 1. +1 for your effort in *trying* to refute my claim. You haven't refuted it. If you would have refuted it you would have proven it false with proof in form of an answer such as a working html/css example. 2. I sure hope CSS 3 has more advanced layout mechanisms because issues like this have always driven me nuts with CSS, when they were so easy using a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply min-height:100% to the first element of the body.

Put the header inside the content div or create a min-height:100% wrapper div.

Comment: I have a min-height:100% wrapper div called "div#container".

Answer (score 0):

Try this code then :

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
    background:gray ;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#666;
}



div#container {
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */
    width:750px;
    background:#f0f0f0;

    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */
}

div#header {
    padding:1em;
    background:#ddd url("../csslayout.gif") 98% 10px no-repeat;
    border-bottom:6px double gray;
}


div#content {
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
    position:relative; /* needed for footer positioning*/
    margin:0 auto; /* center, not in IE5 */

    height:auto !important; /* real browsers */
    height:100%; /* IE6: treaded as min-height*/

    min-height:100%; /* real browsers */            
}
div#content_subdiv{
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
    background:#999;
   color:#fff;    }  
< div id="header "> 
    < h1 >CSS layout: 100% height with header and footer</ h1 > 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget massa dolor, rhoncus tempor nunc. Donec tempor odio eget purus vehicula auctor. </p> 
</div> 

<div id="content"> 

    <p> 
Aenean quam mauris, iaculis non aliquet quis, facilisis sed turpis. Cras id erat velit, nec bibendum erat. Vivamus feugiat purus vitae velit dictum in vestibulum ante tristique. Vestibulum ut massa vel justo eleifend consectetur eget ut nisi. Phasellus ut diam nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent blandit gravida facilisis. Donec elementum faucibus gravida. Nullam nec enim velit, ac scelerisque justo. Pellentesque lacus metus, adipiscing nec congue a, volutpat sollicitudin eros. Donec tortor leo, tempor non viverra at, molestie sed dui. Nullam ipsum purus, tempus elementum tincidunt id, iaculis at lectus. Vestibulum viverra mi in mauris ultrices sollicitudin
    </p> 

</div> <div id="content_subdiv"> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /> this sub div not stretching to 100%; <br /></div>
```

Comment: close, but no cigar. What this code does is make the #content_subdiv act as a footer and stretch the content.