# Child div 100% height

Tags: css, html, height

A more convoluted example of this question is here: [child div height of 100% being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945326/child-div-height-of-100-being-ignored) (a working solution is yet to be found)

Validating test case for my question: http://www.elucidatedbinary.com/tmp/layouttest_100percentheight.html. I want the #main div (yellow background) to expand to 100% of the height of it's parent div (#container).

My question is simple, can this be done without

1. Reverting to jQuery (yucky!) or
2. Reverting to tables (yuckier!)

I am yet to find a single example of how this can be done using the CSS layout model.

Thankyou.

EDIT: When I say "expand to 100% of the height of it's parent div" I mean expand all the way to beneath the footer. The header is supposed to leave a pink gap at the top.

Comment: jQuery is most certainly not "yucky"!

Comment: Wow. What a fast comment. I meant yucky as in there will be a delay when the page loads before the content reshapes itself. Most certinaly yucky in this case.

Comment: using jQuery to make the layout work is certainly "yucky"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
#main { position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: just change the top to `top:120px;` to keep the gap

Comment: I've found that the top/bottom approach doesn't extend the container's background colour once you start scrolling. It's not clear from the OP's question whether this would be a problem.